# Using R(D)COM for integrating R with C#

Tags: c#, r

I am trying to use R(D)Com interface. I have R 2.12.1 installed on machine. For using this interface in C#, I loaded rscproxy_1.3-1 package and then installed R_Scilab_DCOM3.0-1B5 on my machine. Also, I copied sciproxy.dll from Program Files\R(D)COM Server\Scilab to Program Files\R(D)COM Server\bin, as informed while installing the interface.

### **My Problem:**

As a part of testing, I tried the code from blog post http://vvella.blogspot.com/2010/08/integrate-c-net-and-r-taking-best-of.html. But my form application failed due to exception raised by statement rconn.Init(“R”). The exception text was Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040013 I tried to run samples from Programs->R->R(D)COM Server->Server 01 Basic Test. On launched form, I clicked button “Start R” but it failed with error printed in text box as “Initializing R...Function call failed Code: -2147221485 Text: installation problem: unable to load connector”

### I tried this:

I tried to troubleshoot it with the help of Index html page, and there under installation section, I found that there must be rproxy.dll under installed R/Bin folder. Also, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\R-core\R\InstallPath should point to installation folder.

Things lacking on my machine are

- the installed R/bin folder doesn’t
  contain rproxy.dll. Where can I get
  this dll? Or is it sciproxy.dll
  instead?
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\R-core\R\InstallPath
  points to installation folder, but
  there is no entry under
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software.

I can guess there is something fishy about installation, or registering COM server. But I am not successful in figuring it out.

Could you please tell me where am I going wrong?

thanks,

Kapil

Comment: Start with something simpler than a form - try a console app to begin with and put mrnye's code into `Main`.

Comment: Also, I remember that there was a bug in the old versions that meant rcom had to be installed in the default library location (`R.home("library")`) or the connection couldn't be found.  Don't know whether that's been fixed yet.

Comment: Hi Kapil, if you got the solution for this problem, please reply with the solution. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh god I remember this being a huge pain in the arse.  Lets see if I can remember...  And before I start, I warn you that I just "got this working" and never cared to work out if I could remove parts from the process.

Downloads are available from http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html .  If I remember correctly, the RandFriends package is all you need, it installs a crapload (just install it all) but is simple.  Alternatively, I think if you install the 'rscproxy' package in R you can just download the 'statconnDCOM' and install that.  Memory is hazy, but I know one of these methods results in an annoying splash screen everytime you run your C# executable, and one doesn't.  Although that could have just been some setting I played with.

Now, I can't remember how you verify that stuff has installed successfully.  Pretty sure it comes with examples though.  Once that is started, get your C# project open.  Reference the following projects,

```
StatConnectorCommonLib
STATCONNECTORSRVLib
```

In your code, you will probably want to implement a `IStatConnectorCharacterDevice` so you get the R output coming back out in C#.  Your code to initialise will then look something like,

```
private StatConnector _StatConn;
private IStatConnectorCharacterDevice _CharDevice;

private Whatever()
{
  // declare
  _StatConn = new StatConnectorClass();
  _CharDevice = new MyCharDevice();

  // init R, wire up char device
  _StatConn.Init("R");
  _StatConn.SetCharacterOutputDevice(_CharDevice);
}
```

Then you should be able to just use the functions as needed

```
_StatConn.EvaluateNoReturn("x <- 3");
var returnObj = _StatConn.Evalute("1 + 1");
```

Hope that helps.

tl;dr **download RAndFriends, do fresh install with that**

Comment: Thanks @mrnye for your answer. RAndFriend Package worked just fine for me.Download this package without any proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem calling R.Init(), I found R.GetErrorText() returns the actual error message